# JPA: will em.clear() after em.flush() change transactional semantics?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, eclipselink

In `JPA`, is it guaranteed that the **transactional semantics** (=effects from the database point of view) of the following snippets are identical?

**Snippet A**

```
EntityManager em = ...
List<Work> workList = ...
for(Work work : workList)
{
  doWork(work); //may change some entities
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**Snippet B**

```
EntityManager em = ...
List<Work> workList = ... 
for(Work work : workList)
{
  doWork(work); //may change some entities
  em.flush(); 
  em.clear();
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**In other words**:
 Can `em.clear()` after `em.flush(`) **change transactional semantics** (beside the fact the `em.clear()` detaches all entities; it can be assumed that `doWork()` is capable of dealing with that)?

Answer (score 1):

Flush pushes all changes into the database; clear will do nothing to rollback or undo those changes as it only affects what is currently loaded in the context.  em.flush() followed by em.clear() is a common pattern used to reduce the number of loaded entities used in a long running transaction while work proceeds in the same transaction.